# Adding and uploading imagefield to the inbuilt django user model in rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I need the code for adding user image to the inbuilt User model in django rest framework. I do need the code for serializers, views and settings for directory of image
I tried almost everything but completely unable to add it. my code for user registration is given but there is no models.py as I am using inbuilt User model

Views.py

```
class SignUp(APIView):

def post(self, request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
password_confirmation = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
username = serializers.CharField(allow_null=False)
email = serializers.EmailField(allow_null=False)
first_name = serializers.CharField(allow_null=False)
last_name = serializers.CharField(allow_null=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
    instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
    if password is not None:
        instance.set_password(password)
    instance.save()
    return instance

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        if attr == 'password':
            instance.set_password(value)
        else:
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer a simple way, then it would be relating an Image model with every `User` through a OneToOne Relationship,

In your models.py,

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

serializers.py,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password_confirmation = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    avatar = serializers.ImageField(source='image.file')        

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation',
              'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar',
              )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        # print(validated_data)
        image = validated_data.pop('image')
        print(image)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        if image is not None:
            obj = Image(user=instance, **image)
            obj.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)
            elif attr == 'image':
                image = Image.objects.get(user=instance)
                image.file = validated_data.get('image')['file']
                image.save()
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py,

```
class HomeView(APIView):

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Adding a field to the in built `User` model would be an unnecessary workaround. If you could manage to keep the additional attributes independent from the in built models, it'd be more reliable in case if refactoring ever needed.

Comment: Would you then do me a favour and tag the answer as selected?

Answer (score 0):

in your models you can use  `FileField` or `ImageField`

```
upload = models.FileField(upload_to='path/')
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='path')
```

for more detais about fields in django models you can refer to [this_link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/)